# Angularjs Two Way data binding does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am calling a function on ng-click that should update the html with a value from a JSON data.

I have no idea how this is supposed to work or what I am doing wrong here?

My code looks like this:

```
 <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class="head">
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price(Rs.)</th>
                <th>Add to Cart</th>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows | filter:search | orderBy:'product'"  >
                <td>{{row.product}}</td>
                <td>{{row.description}}</td>
                <td>{{row.price}}</td>
              <td><a ng-click="addToCart(price)">Add to cart</a></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Below is my bin  http://jsbin.com/UBIwOsE/2/

Can some one help me telling that how do I update the div with red border. I need to update it with the name of the book and its price on clicking Add to cart.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You have a few errors in your bin.

1) there was `ng-click="{{addToChat(price)}}"`. Of course, `{{ }}` should be deleted.

2) your `addToCart()` was not finished

I have updated your bin http://jsbin.com/UBIwOsE/5/

```
// In your controller

// init variables
$scope.price = $scope.selected = 0;

// fired with ng-click()
$scope.addToCart = function(price) { 
   $scope.price += Math.abs(price);
   $scope.selected++;
}

// In your template

// 1) the ng-click directive looks like this
 <td><a ng-click="addToCart(row.price)">Add to cart</a></td>

// 2) show infos
<div class="cart">
   You have {{selected}} books and Total cost is {{price}}
</div>
```

It works, but it's not perfect. Have a look, learn from it, and read more tutorials about angularjs (I advise you to watch http://egghead.io videos, free and well made)

---

**question 2** (from comments)

I have updated the bin http://jsbin.com/UBIwOsE/11/

```
<!-- template -->

<!--  the parameter sent is the object itself (row instead of row.price) -->
<a ng-click="addToCart(row)">Add to cart</a>

<!-- ... ->

    You have {{books.length}} books and Total cost is {{price}}<br />
<!-- ng-show shows or hides the element based on the expression. -->
<div ng-show="books.length > 0">
  These books are 
    <ul>
      <!-- ng-repeat duplicates the template for each element in the collection. -->
      <li ng-repeat="book in books">{{book.product}} ( {{book.price}} )</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

--

```
// controller

// we push the object into the array, so that we can access to all the data into the template ( {{book.product}} - {{book.price}} )
// $scope.selected is useless now. The array's length is enough
// we keep $scope.price because it's easier than recalculating it from the array. 
$scope.addToCart = function(row) {
    $scope.price += row.price;
    $scope.books.push(row);
}
```

---

Now, you have to track duplicates elements in `$scope.books`
There are lots of way to do that. My favorite looks like http://jsbin.com/UBIwOsE/12

I have done lots of work. Your turn to work : understand what's going on. Do not improve this code if you don't understand it well.

Comment: Thanks so much, I owe a treat to you? But I have 2 things to ask. why did you use Math.abs, I got it to work without that, Also how do I display books as well though I am able to alert the book and push that into array.
http://jsbin.com/UBIwOsE/10/

Comment: I have updated my response. Btw, Math.abs() is not required, it's just an habit I have. (it makes sure that the price isnt negative)

Comment: Thanks a Ton. Just a minor niggle, why wont my bin append a br tag to the book  http://jsbin.com/UBIwOsE/13/

also why does this work $scope.books = $scope.books.concat(product) but this does not $scope.books.concat(product);

Comment: because angular.js protect HTML. Use `ng-repeat` instead (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat)

Comment: @Utopik can you please explain what you mean by `your addToCart() was not finished`. I can't find diff in the `addToCart()` code

Answer (score 1):

It should be `row.price` in `ng-click`.

```
<td><a ng-click="addToCart(row.price)">Add to cart</a></td>
```